# Classifying representations of $G = C_m \times C_n$

Tags: representation-theory

I have been set the following problem:

> Classify representations of $G = C_m \times C_n$; the direct product of two finite cyclic groups.

My first thought is to rewrite $G$ in terms of its presentation:

$G = \langle x,y \ | \ x^m = y^n = 1, xy=yx \rangle$.

From here, we see that $x \mapsto exp({\frac{2\iota k\pi}{m}})$, for $k = 0, 1, ..., m-1$ and $y \mapsto exp({\frac{2 \iota t\pi}{n}})$, for $t = 0, 1, ..., n-1$.  Hence, we would get $mn$ different (one-dimensional) representations.

I almost feel as though this is too easy though, and that I may have made a mistake somewhere, or missed out on some subtle point (I'm worried that this may only work with $m$ and $n$ are coprime or something).  However, I cannot think of another way to tackle the problem.

Is my classification correct, or have I missed some subtle point which makes this all horribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed correct. To see this, you need to show that none of the constructed representations are isomorphic (for example by computing their characters). That these are all of them then follows since the number of irreducible representations is the same as the number of conjugacy classes, and for abelian groups, this is precisely the order of the group.